# How to fix Warning: session_start(): in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I just configured an existing WordPress project. Now I am facing this issue.

```
Warning: session_start(): open(C:\xampp\htdocs\Nadesh\reportlink\sess_2u6p774c1s5utr299m1qqgh99e, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in D:\xampp\htdocs\Nadesh\reportlink\wp-content\themes\enfold\config-templatebuilder\avia-shortcodes\masonry_entries.php on line 33

Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: C:\xampp\htdocs\Nadesh\reportlink) in D:\xampp\htdocs\Nadesh\reportlink\wp-content\themes\enfold\config-templatebuilder\avia-shortcodes\masonry_entries.php on line 33

Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in D:\xampp\htdocs\Nadesh\reportlink\wp-includes\class.wp-scripts.php on line 447
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you wanna fix the reason of the issue or just get rid of the Warning?
Have you tried to switch debug mode to false in wp-config.php?

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Enfold" theme file try to run `session_start()` function and access the system folder to read session data but it cannot since the file/folder does not exist.

To fix the problem you need to change `session.save_path` var (nonexistent path) in your php settings.
First try to find it in `php.ini` file.
You can also check the `.htaccess` file in the root of your site.

I can make an assumption that the problem can be caused by running your web server on the `C:\` drive and the site files location on the `D:/` drive.